# How do I sort a table that is referenced by another table?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have this table that is made from reference to other table.

[image: table]

and now I want to sort from small to largest the third column, but since it is referenced from another table is not sorting. And I also dont want excel to sort the reference table and I need the table to be referenced because I will change some values on the reference table and I need them to be connected, so I just cant copy and paste the values and then sort.

Could you give me some help?

Comment: What is the third column? D? Also, how are you referencing them?

Comment: @Sun yes. For example at B2 I have =B20, at C2 I have =C20 and at D2 I have =D20

Comment: Is your source table in the same sheet?

Comment: I only have an idea that would involve helper columns, does your sheet structure allow that?

Comment: Another question, do you or could you have duplicates in Column D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I went ahead and built a small example:

[image]

The formulas are as follows:

The 3 in Row 20 are to be copied downwards with `PasteSpecial>Formulas`:

in E20: `=IFERROR(RANK($D20,$D$20:$D$33,1),"")`

in F20: `=IF(ISNUMBER($D20),"",(COUNTIF($D$20:$D$33,"<"&$D20)+1)+COUNTIF($D$20:$D20,$D20)-1)`

in G20: `=IF($E20="",(MAX($E$20:$E$33)+$F20),$E20)`

The formula in B3 is to be copied into the whole target table with `PasteSpecial>Formulas`:

in B2: `=INDEX(B$20:B$33,MATCH(ROW()-1,$G$20:$G$33,0),1)`

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Note: this is designed to work even if you have duplicates in column D

Comment: thanks for the help, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This method only works if the entries in the column you are sorting on are unique.  You will need to adjust the address ranges to suit your data.

The formulas in the each column start from X and finishing in Z as you move left are as follows:

```
=INDEX($X$41:$X$47,MATCH(ROWS($Z$29:Z29),COUNTIF($Z$41:$Z$47,"<="&$Z$41:$Z$47),0))

=INDEX($Y$41:$Y$47,MATCH(ROWS($Z$29:Z29),COUNTIF($Z$41:$Z$47,"<="&$Z$41:$Z$47),0))

=INDEX($Z$41:$Z$47,MATCH(ROWS($Z$29:Z29),COUNTIF($Z$41:$Z$47,"<="&$Z$41:$Z$47),0))
```

Note only the range right after INDEX is changing.  Thes are CSE or array formulas.  It means you need to press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you are done editing your cell.  Then copy the individual cell and paste it in the rows below the copied cell.  pasting including the source cell or dragging down MAY not work.  Repeat this for all three columns.

Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]

Comment: Draggin seems to work, but pasting over the original source cell does not.  These array formulas apply to a single cell, and that single cell gets copied down.  It is not an array formula that is applied to the column all in one shot

Comment: Thanks for the help :)